# How to move/copy entire file from one branch to another with Git / IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, branch

I want to copy not changes, but entire files, which are not present, to on one branch, from another.

It this possible with either Git or IntelliJ?

Currently I am opening diff and copy paste files. But this way I can easily misspell file name and/or file location. Can I add some automation here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there has an easier way to copy all the files from a branch to another branch by git.

Assume copy all the files from `branchA` to `branchB`, then you can execute below commands (also can execute in IntelliJ idea termainal window):

```
git checkout branchB
git checkout branchA -- .
git commit -m 'copy files from branchA to branchB'
```

Comment: How to select just certain files?

Comment: You can use certain filenames or wildcard. Such as copy `*.txt` from `branchA` to `branchB`, you can use `git checkout branchA -- *.txt` instead.

Comment: I don't understand, is `checkout` command has additional functionality to copy? `git checkout branchA -- filename` copies filename from `branchA` to current branch without switching to `branchA`?

Comment: Yes, it does. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: @Dims Yes, git checkout command has many functions more than switch to another branch.

Answer (score 4):

UPD. Since IntelliJ 2018.3, there is the Get action available inside the Compare with Working tree dialog.

Old reply:
Command-line git can do this, but it is not possible from the Compare branches in IntelliJ. There is a request to add mentioned functionality - please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95494

As a workaround one could youse the Get action from a file Git history.

There is also a plugin to achieve this https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10795-git-checkout-files-from-branch

Comment: How to do with command line Git?

Comment: See Marina's reply

Comment: Back to Eclipse then! :)